# Creating UML class diagram for entrance system?

Tags: uml, diagram, class-design, class-diagram

I am looking at the entrance system of a climbing gym. The customer enters the building, gives their details to the receptionist, the receptionist enters the details into the database, verifies the details, the receptionist takes a payment if the customer is not a member and the customer proceeds inside.

I have four classes: customer, receptionist, administrator, database.
I have non-member and member generalized under customer.
there is a many to one relationship between customer and receptionist (many at customer end). one to one relationship between receptionist and database. one to one relationship between receptionist and administrator.

[image]

Are my classes and relationships correct?

Comment: You could place your pic on a public server for now.

Comment: [link](https://s18.postimg.org/y87da00ux/systems_class.jpg)

Comment: I'll have a look later. There are a couple of issues with your design.

Comment: Ok thank you. FYI - I haven't finished my attributes or operations in that image.

Answer (score 2):

So here are my observations:

- All attributes/operations shall start with a lower case letter (and as you did all classes with an upper case letter). This is a common convention adopted in the list of all languages I know (which is definitely not complete, but it's more than one or two)
- You use shared composition with `Member` and `Non-Member`. It rather looks like this should be a generalization relation. So you need to use and unfilled triangle instead of the diamond.
- You should use role names with the associations. That is you should note `administrator` towards the `Administrator` class. That will make it an attribute `administrator` of type `Administrator` inside `Receptionist`.
- You should not define the `ID` attributes in a draft/business model. The ID is usually derived when compiling later from the object address. So you reference the object per se, not an ID.
- There is a relation between `Receptionist` and `Database`. I don't think it's a wise design decision here. It's unclear what the database will be used for. Probably each and any class will somehow be mirrored in a database. So instead those classes should implement a `Serializable` interface which allows to mirror them in a database. Having `Database` as class in a business model is not right. Just concentrate on the business objects and implement a persistence layer in a later stage.
- From your description I don't see where the `Administrator` comes in. It seems quite paranoid to have one admin per receptionist.

Answer (score 0):

that's not easy to answer. You talk about classes so I assume you are creating a class diagram. If so, I'm not sure I would include a receptionist class (at least not for that use case). A receptionist may exist in a data flow diagram. In a class diagram, a receptionist class may exist within a staff rota or staff payment process. Within the entry system from a programming point of view, how does your customer class interact with the receptionist class? What methods does the receptionist class contain for that interaction? I would assume none, the real human receptionist interacts with the real life customer, but the customer class would not interact with the receptionist class, unless you were logging which receptionist processed the transaction.

Even in that situation i would assume it would be another class that managed that action.

If you are simply mapping the interactions between real human people, then I would suggest, many customers could be served by many individual receptionists. I assume they employ more than one.

Comment: Yes I am mapping the human interaction. then making another class diagram with a significant security change - for example a fingerprint scanner or code to enter.